# wscelery monitoring tool super function error

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, celery, django-celery

I'm trying to follow https://wscelery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html the link with django. No problem starting or using celery commands:

```
celery wscelery --allow-origin=.*
```

from terminal gives the error:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/wscelery/events.py", line 71, in __init__
    super().__init__()
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

I know what this error means, but I can not use Python3.

Wscelery pip link:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wscelery

Requirements

Python >= 3.4

Is there anyone using wscelery with python2?

Comment: From a look at the github page it's a rather new project which was obviously started with Python 3 only in mind, so I don't think you can expect any Python 2 support unless you implement it yourself.

Comment: So if I dont use wscelery, is there any alternative that I want to take results progress like started and progress bar